# What is the Scala type mapping for all Spark SQL DataType

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sqldatatypes

The different `DataType`s available for Spark SQL can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataTypes.html). Can anyone please tell me what would be the corresponding Java/Scala data type for each of Spark SQL's `DataType`s?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Directly from the [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html):

```
Data type       |    Value type in Scala
------------------------------------------------
ByteType        |    Byte   
ShortType       |    Short  
IntegerType     |    Int    
LongType        |    Long   
FloatType       |    Float  
DoubleType      |    Double     
DecimalType     |    java.math.BigDecimal
StringType      |    String
BinaryType      |    Array[Byte]
BooleanType     |    Boolean 
TimestampType   |    java.sql.Timestamp
DateType        |    java.sql.Date
ArrayType       |    scala.collection.Seq   
MapType         |    scala.collection.Map   
StructType      |    org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

Comment: is there a mapping like this for Java?

Answer (score 7):

For those trying to find the Java types, they're now also hosted at the link from [zero323's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32899979/2738164).  To document the current revision here:

```
Data type     |    Value type in Java              |    API to access or create a data type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ByteType      |    byte or Byte                    |    DataTypes.ByteType
ShortType     |    short or Short                  |    DataTypes.ShortType
IntegerType   |    int or Integer                  |    DataTypes.IntegerType
LongType      |    long or Long                    |    DataTypes.LongType
FloatType     |    float or Float                  |    DataTypes.FloatType
DoubleType    |    double or Double                |    DataTypes.DoubleType
DecimalType   |    java.math.BigDecimal            |    DataTypes.createDecimalType() or DataTypes.createDecimalType(precision, scale).
StringType    |    String                          |    DataTypes.StringType
BinaryType    |    byte[]                          |    DataTypes.BinaryType
BooleanType   |    boolean or Boolean              |    DataTypes.BooleanType
TimestampType |    java.sql.Timestamp              |    DataTypes.TimestampType
DateType      |    java.sql.Date                   |    DataTypes.DateType
ArrayType     |    java.util.List                  |    DataTypes.createArrayType(elementType) or DataTypes.createArrayType(elementType, containsNull).
MapType       |    java.util.Map                   |    DataTypes.createMapType(keyType, valueType) or DataTypes.createMapType(keyType, valueType, valueContainsNull)
StructType    |    org.apache.spark.sql.Row        |    DataTypes.createStructType(fields)
StructField   |    The value type in Java of the   |    DataTypes.createStructField(name, dataType, nullable)
              |    data type of this field (For    |
              |    example, int for a StructField  |
              |    with the data type IntegerType) |
```

One thing of note when working with StructTypes in particular - it appears that, if you wish to declare an empty StructType in another as a placeholder value, you must use a `new StructType()` rather than the suggested `DataTypes.createStructType((StructField)null)` to prevent null pointers.  Remember to instantiate the nested StructType with StructFields prior to usage.